# Assert on Arrays

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<assert.h>
const char *authour ="Alexandre Santos";
int ints_get(int *a)
{
    int result = 0;
    int x;
    while (scanf("%d", &x) !=EOF)
    {
        a[result++] = x;
    }
    return result;
}


int sum_odd(const int *a, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        if(i%2 != 0)
            sum += a[i];
    return sum;
}
int sum_all(const int *a, int n)
{
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum = sum + a[i];
    return sum;
}

int final(const int *a, int n)
{
    return sum_all(a,n) - sum_odd(a,n);
}

void unit_test_even_values_minus_odd_values(void){
    int a1[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    assert(final(a1, 8) == 4);
    assert(final(a1, 6) == 3);
    assert(final(a1, 4) == 2);
    assert(final(a1, 2) == 1); 
}

void unit_tests(void){
    unit_test_even_values_minus_odd_values();
}


void test_sum(void)
{
    int a[100];
    int n = ints_get(a);
    int total = final(a,n);
    printf("%d\n", total);
}



int main()
{
    test_sum();
    return 0;
}
```

I have this program but I don't understand how the assertions work here, my main question is what the second number represents. For example I understand that `assert(final(a1, 8) == 4)` I understand that `a1` is the array determined in the line above but I can't understand the second number `(8)`.... Can anyone explain to me how this works? I tried to search a little bit but I still don't understand...

Comment: You are actually asking what `final` function does. That is nothing related to `assert`. Just that whoever wrote that code wants to verify that a function call with certain parameters returns a specific value. To dig into that, you can completely forget about `assert` for the moment.

Comment: Looking at the function `final`, the second parameter is the number of values in the array that shall be handled by the function.

Comment: `while (scanf("%d", &x) !=EOF)` is an infinite loop with non-numeric text input.  Use `while (scanf("%d", &x) == 1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument to `final` is the number of values to work on from that array, starting from the beginning.

`final(a1, 8)` sums all eight values. `final(a1, 6)` only sums the first six values.